# Debian PXE pre-seed file

Tags: keyboard, debian-installer, pxe, autologin

I've done a first PXE installation with Debian 7 and I'm currently trying to make another one for Debian 8.
I'm stuck with 3 little things and I cannot find any solution.

- Skip missing firmware
- Keyboard language (from EN to FR)
- Auto-login

Here is what I tried (written on a file called `my-debian-8.cfg`):

```
#skip missing firmware
d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean false

# keyboard
d-i console-keymaps-at/keymap select fr-latin9
d-i debian-installer/keymap string fr-latin9
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select fr
# auto-login
d-i passwd/auto-login boolean true

#my desktop
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect desktop, system, lxde-desktop
```

I found [example-preseed.txt](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/example-preseed.txt) that gave me a lot of things but these 2 configurations are not working.

Here is my  boot file:

```
# /var/lib/ftfpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default
prompt 0
timeout 10

default install
menu title PXE Boot Menu

label My Installation
    menu label ^Debian 8 (Jessie)
    menu default
    kernel debian-8-installer/i386/linux url=http://192.168.3.1/my-debian-8.cfg netcfg/get_domain=192.168.3.1 netcfg/get_hostname=myUser languagechooser/language-name=French countrychooser/shortlist=FR debian-installer/locale=fr_FR.UTF-8 keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap=fr
    append vga=788 initrd=debian-8-installer/i386/initrd.gz -- quiet



default debian-8-installer/i386/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32
```

For the missing firmware, it's obviously a network one. Here are references I have:

```
# First asking
iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode

# Second
rtl_nic/ntl18168g-2.fw
```

I've found `ntl18168g-2.fw` coming from a `deb` package (which I had tested before) that I've unpacked but I don't know where to add it on my `initrd.gz` archive. 
To unpacked and recompile `initrd.gz` archive I've done as it was written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524888/debian-missing-firmware-with-pxe-installation). It works like a charm. I didn't find

Where am I suppose to add `ntl18168g-2.fw` file? What about `.ucode` or simply skip missing firmware? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
It seems not coming from `lxde` because with `open box` I have the same problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`iwlwifi` is a non free firmware , according to [NetbootFirmware](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/NetbootFirmware) you need to add the non-free firmware to `Initramfs`:

> Initramfs is essentially a concatenation of gzipped cpio archives which are extracted into a ramdisk and used as an early userspace by the Linux kernel. Debian Installer's initrd.gz is in fact a single gzipped cpio archive containing all the files the installer needs at boot time. By simply appending another gzipped cpio archive - containing the firmware files we are missing - we get the show on the road!

Add debs from `firmware.cpio.gz` :

```
# cd to the directory where you have your initrd
cd /tftpboot/debian-installer/i386
[ -f initrd.gz.orig ] || cp -p initrd.gz initrd.gz.orig
[ -f firmware.cpio.gz ] || wget http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/stable/current/firmware.cpio.gz
cat initrd.gz.orig firmware.cpio.gz > initrd.gz
```

Enable the non-free repository  by preseeding the following:

```
base-config     apt-setup/non-free      boolean true
```

**Keyboard language**

To convert your keyboard from **Eng** to **Fr** edit your `my-debian-8.cfg` like :

```
# Locales
d-i debian-installer/fallbacklocale select fr_FR.UTF-8
d-i debian-installer/locale select fr_FR.UTF-8
# Keyboard
d-i console-keymaps-at/keymap select fr-latin9
d-i debian-installer/keymap string fr-latin9
```

**Auto-login**
For security reasons, the best way _for_PXE_installation_ is to skip the configuation of sudo and root account using the following lines:

```
# Skip creation of a root account 
d-i passwd/root-login boolean false
# Skip creation of a normal user account.
d-i passwd/make-user boolean false
```

**Edit**

You can verify your configuration file from [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-pxe-install-server-for-multiple-linux-distributions-on-debian-lenny)

To set up the netboot file :

```
cd /var/lib/tftpboot/
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian8.4/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz
tar xfz netboot.tar.gz
```

Verify the structure:

```
tree /var/lib/tftpboot/
```

or

```
ls -la /var/lib/tftpboot
```

**edit2**

install DNSMASQ server:

```
apt-get install dnsmasq
```

edit `dnsmasq.conf` and use the following example:

```
interface=eth0
domain=debian.lan
dhcp-range=192.168.1.3,192.168.1.253,255.255.255.0,1h
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,pxeserver,192.168.1.100
pxe-prompt="Press F8 for menu.", 60
 #pxe-service types: x86PC, PC98, IA64_EFI, Alpha, Arc_x86, Intel_Lean_Client,   IA32_EFI, BC_EFI, Xscale_EFI and X86-64_EFI
pxe-service=x86PC, "Install Debian 8 Linux from network server   192.168.1.100", pxelinux
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/srv/tftp
```

And restart DNSMASQ services:

```
service dnsmasq restart
```

The easy way is to download `netboot.tar.gz` to `/srv/tftp/`

```
cd /srv/tftp/
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian8.4/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz
tar xfz netboot.tar.gz
chmod -R 755 /srv/tftp/
```

Allow port from ufw

```
 ufw allow 69/udp
 ufw allow 67/udp
 ufw allow 53/tcp
 ufw allow 53/udp
```

Reboot

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, none is working. If I set locales and keyboard (or add missing firmware) as you said, my install is trying to access distant mirror but there's not any web connection (only local). Then this apt config failed (I need to press `ok`) and finally software installation failed (probably because of previous failure. For the keyboard it's not working. I've tried that. But if I erase any keyboard config and select it manually when asked it's working

Comment: For the autologin, I've updated `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` as said on the wiki : https://wiki.debian.org/fr/LightDM

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question but how am I suppose to add packages (coming from website you gave me) on my server? I've just mounted an ISO. This means I cannot add it manually where it's supposed to be (http://192.168.3.1/debian-8/dists/jesies/non-free/binary-i386/Packages). Do I need to recreate my own ISO file?

Comment: You don't need to create an ISO , the boot from the network, via PXE, requires three things: a local DHCP server, a TFTP server and host which supports the ability to actually boot over the network. try this https://www.unix-experience.fr/2013/installation-automatisee-de-debian-par-le-reseau/

Comment: I've all of this but my install requires files at this url : http://192.168.3.1/debian-8/dists/jesies/non-free/binary-i386/Packages. However, my ISO (mounted on my server to distribute needed files) doesn't contains `non-free/binary-i386/Packages`. I don't know how to tell the install to teach somewhere else. By the way, I try recreating a new ISO and it works.. Not easy to maintain but working.. Better idea?

Comment: Edit your `/var/lib/tftpboot` and add `http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian8.4/non-free/binary-i386/`

Comment: Could you be more specific please? Directly on the folder `/var/lib/tftpboot`? By the way, you were right about keyboard. The only missing point is that the keyboard MUST NOT be connected to the computer during PXE installation.

Comment: It's not working when I'm adding the folder directly on `var/lib/tftpboot`. Could you please add more details? Thanks again for your time!